# I need help accessing an objects properites

Tags: javascript

I have an object wihtin a functions properties and I don't know how to access that objects properties, change them, add to it or remove them from hte object:

```
function Example(test) {
    test={};
    test.firstTry='One';
    test.secondTry='Two'; 
    console.log(test);
}
x=new Example("I don't know where to go from here, I want to access test.firstTry and test.secondTry");
```

Comment: you can't access them outside the function, they are unknown to outer world

Comment: Thanks all, I did forget 'this' and I also forgot '[...]' in the instantiation of Example.  It should have been x=new Example(['...']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `test` a property on the `Example` object use `this` within the constructor.

```
 function Example(test){
    this.test={};
    this.test.firstTry='One';
    this.test.secondTry='Two'; 
 }

var x = new Example({});
console.log(x.test.firstTry);
```

Answer (score 1):

Those properties are members of an object that is only available in a local variable inside the function. There is no way to access them outside the function unless you modify the function.

You could expose the variable as an object property.

```
this.test = test;
```

and then

```
x.test.firstTry;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `new` keyword, you should use `this`:

```
function Example() {
    this.firstTry  = 'One';
    this.secondTry = 'Two';
}

var x = new Example();
console.log(x);
```

Output: `Example {firstTry: "One", secondTry: "Two"}`

You could also return an object instead:

```
function Example() {
    var test = {};
    test.firstTry  = 'One';
    test.secondTry = 'Two';
    return test;
}

var x = Example();
console.log(x);
```

Output: `Object {firstTry: "One", secondTry: "Two"}`

Answer (score 0):

See this http://jsfiddle.net/kukiwon/fFzWh/. You forgot to add a return statement.

```
function Example(test){
    test={};
    test.firstTry='One';
    test.secondTry='Two'; 
    return test;
}

var x=new Example("I don't know where to go from here, I want to access test.firstTry and test.secondTry");
alert(x.firstTry);
alert(x.secondTry);
```